# Insert row into table if join doesn't match or field is null

Tags: mysql

Please excuse the awkward title for this question.

I am trying to keep track of the prices of some products, ideally without having a load of entries with the same product_id and price (different dates). There are 160,000 products and the update is run every day.

I have the following tables:

**products**

```
product_id, price, date_added, date_updated
(id Primary Key)
```

**price_index**

```
product_id, price, date_updated
(product_id, price, date_updated primary unique)
```

I am doing the following query, however I cannot sort the select/join by the most recent date.

```
INSERT INTO price_index 
(SELECT p.product_id,p.product_price,p.date_updated FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN price_index pi ON (p.product_id = pi.product_id) 
WHERE (p.product_price <> pi.product_price OR pi.product_price IS NULL))
```

If I replace the JOIN with

```
JOIN (SELECT * FROM price_index ORDER BY date_updated DESC) pi
```

It will do the correct sorting first, however this doesn't seem to use any indexed and keeps freezing my MySQL GUI tool.

Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do here?

UPDATE:
The update script updates the products table with the current price first. I then need to perform the check/update on the price_index table.

Comment: I see absolutely ZERO reasons why you would need to order rows there, nor why it should not work in query using joins. Maybe, I just haven't understood your problem correctly.

Comment: Hi David, it seemed to be finding the first entry in the price_index table and not the most recent. I only want to add another row to the price_index table if the most recent price_index is different from the updated products table price.

Comment: I've added a not to clarify

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to insert a new row only when the most recent price has changed.  I'm a little confused about the tables.  Your query mentions three but your text only mentions two.  I'll assume that `product_prices` and `price_index` are the same thing.

```
INSERT INTO product_prices(product_id, price, date_updated)
    SELECT p.product_id, p.product_price, p.date_updated
    FROM products p LEFT JOIN
         price_index pi
         ON p.product_id = pi.product_id AND
            p.product_price = pi.product_price LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT product_id, max(date_updated) as maxdu
          FROM price_index
          GROUP BY product_id
         ) pimax
         ON pi.product_id = pimax.product_id and pi.date_updated = pimax.maxdu
WHERE pimax.product_id IS NULL;
```

This uses a `left join` to look for a match on both the product and the price *and* on the most recent 
update date.  If any of the three conditions do not match, then the insert takes place.

Comment: Apologies - I was trying to keep my table names simple and had missed renaming one instance of product_prices to price_index. Have updated the question.

Comment: I had tried something similar to what you describe, but the query froze on me - perhaps my version was far less efficient? 
INSERT INTO price_index 
(SELECT p.product_id,p.product_price,p.date_updated FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM price_index ORDER BY date_updated DESC) pi ON (p.product_id=pi.product_id) 
WHERE (p.product_price <> pi.product_price OR pi.product_price IS NULL))

Comment: @AlexHolsgrove . . . That is not similar at all, and the `order by` isn't doing anything except preventing you from using indexes on the underlying table.

Comment: Yes, quite right. I've tried running your example but it seems to have locked up. Is this because of the amount of products, or perhaps something else?

Comment: @AlexHolsgrove . . . It could be the number of products or (more probably) the size of the `price_index` table.  I would suggest that you ask another question (can this be sped up?  is there another way to write this query?) and include the execution plan for the query.

Comment: Gordon - thank you. Is there a way to improve this query? The EXPLAIN result is here: http://pbrd.co/1qkwk1a